# Soap UI: Groovy Test Step : How to call a Specific Method in a groovy script from another Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

In my project, I want to keep all groovy utilities test step under one test case and to call them again and again where ever is needed. Like reading the test data file etc. I would be able to achieve that if the below problem is resolved. I tried a lot of ways but couldn't make it. Any help is welcome!!

**For Example**

script 1: test1Script

```
def sayHellow(){
log.info "Hello!!"

}
```

Script 2 : test2Script

```
import groovy.lang.Binding
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def projectPath = groovyUtils.projectPath
def scriptPath = projectPath + "\\GroovyScripts\\"



//GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
//Util = shell.parse(new File(directoryName + "groovyUtilities.groovy"))
//groovyUtilities gu = new groovyUtilities(Util)

// Create Groovy Script Engine to run the script.
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptPath) 

// Load the Groovy Script file 
externalScript = gse.loadScriptByName("sayHello.groovy")  

// Create a runtime instance of script
instance = externalScript.newInstance()

// Sanity check 
assert instance!= null

// run the foo method in the external script
instance.sayhellowTest()
```

When I'm calling that method from another script, I'm getting below exception

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such log for class test1Script`

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that groovy runtime calls your method but it can't find the `log` property. I assume that this `log` variable is declared in the `test1Script` body, e.g. `def log = ...` In this case the variable becomes local to its declaration scope and it's not visible to the script functions. [To make it visible](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_variables), it can be annotated by [@Field](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#xform-Field) or it should be undeclared (doesn’t have type declaration, just `log = ...`). The latter, however, requires you to pass the variable value via so-called bindings when running the script as you run it. So given my assumptions above, you can annotate your `log` variable as a field and it should work:

```
//just for the sake of example it prints to stdout whatever it receives
@groovy.transform.Field
def log = [info: {
    println it
}]

def sayHellow() {
    log.info "Hello!!"
}
```

Now calling `sayHellow` from another script prints "Hello" to stdout:

```
...
instance.sayHellow()
```

Comment: you were right I didn't declare the log variable in my called script, That was causing the issue. I have marked the complete working solution below as well. Thanks for your solution. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to declare, context, testRunner, and Log variables in the called script.

script 1: sayHello.groovy

```
public class groovyUtilities {

    def context
    def testRunner
    def log

    def sayhellowTest() {
        log.info "Hi i'm arpan"
    }
}
```

script 2: RunAnotherGroovyScript.groovy

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def projectPath = groovyUtils.projectPath
def scriptPath = projectPath + "\\GroovyScripts\\"

// Create Groovy Script Engine to run the script and pass the location of the directory of your script.
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptPath)

// Load the Groovy Script file 
externalScript = gse.loadScriptByName("sayHello.groovy")

// Create a runtime instance of script
instance = externalScript.newInstance(context: context, log: log, testRunner: testRunner)

// Sanity check if the instance is null or not
assert instance != null

// run the foo method in the external script
instance.sayhellowTest()
```

Standoutput:

```
Hi i'm arpan
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to keep all groovy utilities test step under one test case and
>   to call them again and again where ever is needed. Like reading the
>   test data file etc."

OK, so to me this simply sounds like you have a library of reusable functions and want to be able to call them from any test you might be running.

I suppose you could store them with another test and then call them from the test you're currently running, but SoapUI comes with the neat feature in that you can store your common functions/libraries 'outside' of the SoapUI project.

I have lots of such Groovy libraries and I store mine under the bin/scripts folder of SoapUI.  I typically call common functions from a Script assertion test step in the test I'm running.  For example, I have a getUserDetails type test step.  I can do all the usual assertions against the step like valid response code, SLA etc.  I can then use a Script assertion test step.  This type of step allows you to run a chunk of Groovy script.  This is OK for specific cases, but you wouldn't want to paste in something common as you need to update every Script assertion if something changes.  But you can call an 'external' groovy script.  Also, the Script Assertion step is just a method that has log, context and message exchange passed into it, so no need to instantiate your own.  Just pass them into you external groovy script...

So, as an illustration...

ValidateUser.groovy (stored in bin/scripts/groovyScripts/yourOrg/common)

```
package groovyScripts.yourOrg.common;  // Package aligns with folder it's stored in.

Class ValidateUser {

    def log = null;
    def context = null;
    def messageExchange = null;

    // Constructor for the class
    ValidateUser(logFromTestStep, contextFromTestStep, messageExchangeFromTestStep) {

        // Assign log, context and messageExchange to the groovy class.
        this.log = logFromTestStep;
        this.context = contextFromTestStep;
        this.messageExhange = messageExchangeFromTestStep;

    }

    def runNameCheck() {

        // Performs some validation.  You have access to the API response via 
        // this.messageExchange

        log.info("Running the Name Check");

    }
}
```

In the test step of interest, go to the assertions and create a 'Script Assertion'  From here you can instantiate your external class and call some method.  E.g.

```
def validateUserObject = new groovyScripts.yourOrg.common.ValidateUser(log, context, messageExchange);

validateUserObject.runNameCheck();
```

What I like about these external type scripts is that I can use any text editor I like.  Also, when I make a change and press Save, SoapUI is monitoring the scripts folder for changes and reloads the script so no need to restart SoapUI.